# Python verbose error in IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

I am attempting to run IDLE from `C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\idle.exe`. When I run it the shell appears but a black screen appears with the following error:

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
KeyError: 'QT_API'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
KeyError: 'QT_API'
```

One link [online](http://www.agapow.net/programming/python/verbose/) suggests that this sort of problem occurs with a Python 2.7 library being seen by a 3.x version Python.

Though this is descriptive, I don't really see how it can fix my problem. I don't know **which version of python I am using** and **what library it is trying to access**. Perhaps this is a good starting point: How can I determine these two things? If anyone has suggestions on how to directly address this error, that would be good too.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I found out how to determine the python version used by typing in the following commands:

```
import sys
print(sys.info)
```

which provides the following output:

```
3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

So now I am left with the second part: **What library is it trying to access?**

Comment: To tell your python version go to your terminal and do `python --version`

Comment: That gives me `Python 3.4.4` ... strange because in IDLE I am getting 3.6.1

Comment: The little idle.exe wrapper in `.../Anaconda/Scripts/`should be trying to execute `.../Anaconda/pythonw.exe -m idlelib`.  Get into the Anaconda directory.  Run `python.exe -VV` and make sure you see 3.6.1.  Then `pythonw.exe -v -m idlelib`.  The `-v` (lowercase!) is the same as setting PYTHONVERBOSE.  "Print a message each time a module is initialized, showing the place (filename or built-in module) from which it is loaded. "